# Log4Net Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net, mstest, log4net-configuration

I am using *log4net* in one of our solutions.  The solution contains multiple projects, each a *Unit-Test* project.  I am using the method described in [this post](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/josh-eastburn/2012/04/10/using-log4net-with-multi-project-solutions) to add logging to the various projects.

I am using a rolling file appender to log all of the tests to a single log file that rolls over based on the size.

Each of my projects log successfully to the log file, however, if I run tests from multiple projects *(multiple test assemblies)*, I only see logging from the first of the assemblies.

For example, if I run tests from *`Project_A`* and *`Project_B`*, I only see logging statements from *`Project_A`* (assuming `Project_A's` tests were run first in the test run)

Things I have already checked:

- I have included the config file in each project as a link
- I have added *`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]`* to each project's assembly file.
- I have tested each project separately to ensure they log successfully when run by themselves.

Comment: Why do you want to log from your unit tests? Can you add what you have so far to the post, as far as the logging code and config section?

Comment: Are you using `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>` inside the `<appender>` configuration?

Comment: @RyanGates: These are Coded UI Tests and the logging is part of an effort to bridge the gap between Automation and Manual testing.

Comment: @madth3: No I am not, I was not aware I needed to add that.  I should add, I am not getting any errors that say that log4net is unable to obtain a lock, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Bump...anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would agree with @madth3 (despite your scepticism). If that doesn't resolve it, then enable internal logging (see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured out the issue and thought I would report back for others in the same dilemma.

Each project's linked config file's property needs to change from Copy Never to Copy If Newer.  Once I made this change, all projects logged to the same file as expected.