# Log from multiple projects in single solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net, log4net-configuration

I've got a solution where I need to log from different assemblies using log4net.  The first project in the solution (*PCBClient.cs*, a web client) logs as expected, but the next one (*WriteUtilities.cs*, backend database functions) doesn't log at all.  I've followed the instructions on [**Falafel.com**](http://blog.falafel.com/using-log4net-with-multi-project-solutions/), as well as the [**follow-on instructions on this SO page**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288206/log4net-multiple-projects), as well as the thread on [**DreamInCode.net**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/108755-to-use-log4net-custom-appender-config-change-only/).

Obviously I'm missing something.

I've added the initial project PCBClient as a reference in WriteUtilities.  I can't do the reciprocal as it would create a circular reference, maybe I need to make the references go the other way?  I've created a new logger in the web.config of PCBClient appending the name of the referenced assembly per the [**log4net FAQ: Can I load an appender from another assembly?**](http:////%20Log4Net%20configuration%20[assembly:%20log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile%20=%20%22Log4Net.config%22,%20Watch%20=%20true)]) using the specified form:

```
<appender name="..." type="MyNamespace.MyAppender, MyAssembly">
```

(I'm reasonably sure I don't need the .cs after the name of the assembly?):

```
  <appender name="WriteUtility_TransactionLog" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender, WriteUtilities">
  <File value="WriteUtilityTransactions.log"/>
  <AppendToFile value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss} %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Created a reference to it in the web.config as well:

```
<logger name="WriteUtility_TransactionLog">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="WriteUtility_TransactionLog"/>
</logger>
```

Then marked the properties of both the web.config in PCBClient and the linked web.config in WriteUtilities as "Copy if newer".

In the assembly WriteUtilities.cs I've added:

```
    private static readonly ILog WriteUtilities_TransactionLog = LogManager.GetLogger("WriteUtility_TransactionLog");
```

In AssemblyInfo.cs in the PCBClient project I've added:

```
// Log4Net configuration
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

And commented out the original logging references in both PCBClient & WriteUtilities so they should both point to the one above (I think):

```
//point at logging .dll
//[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

**I still can't log from the WriteUtilties, what am I missing?**

Answer (score -2):

Change your tag so that it looks like:

```
<log4net debug="true">
```

Perhaps that would be of help to you to solve the mystery.

Comment: What tag are you referring to?  In what file?

Comment: I am referring to your <log4net> ... </log4net> element. In your web.config? Wherever you have your log4net settings specified. This outputs debug information to the console.